# Sudden appearance of action bar in android studio 1.1.0

Tags: android-studio, android-actionbar, xml-layout

Anyone who have experience this? My Android studio updated from 1.0.1 to 1.1.0. When i open my existing application , it was corrupted ( URI are not register error appears, java sources cannot be found, a lot of error) . So i close it and re-import it again. (it works).

But i notice, most of my XML layout using DESIGN mode, there is an ACTION bar, When i try to run the project , there is no Action Bar in the phone. Anyone knows how to remove the action bar in the DESIGN mode?

Anyone knows if i need to delete a file something or settings something in android studio? or i need to clean something?

**I hope i will not do re-installation , although this is my last resort**

Comment: Do you have a `tools:context` or a `tools:showIn` attribute defined in your layout XML?

Comment: @Tanis.7x yes i have like `tools:context=".MainActivity"`

Comment: If you remove that, does it appear as expected in the layout editor?

Comment: @Tanis.7x , NO , nothing was change, i even close and reopen the project

Comment: What theme is your application/activity using?

Comment: im using the default one `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

Answer (score 0):

The Android Studio layout preview tries to guess what theme should be applied to your layout. In your case, Studio probably sees that your application is using a theme with an ActionBar (`Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`) and assumes that you do indeed want an ActionBar.

If you are not using an ActionBar in your application, you should switch to a theme with no ActionBar, such as `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`.

Comment: I have tried it before , even before with errors, I manually change the XML into `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` , re-import the project , close and open it again , clean project and rebuild. But still the same. Another weird thing is, when i create a new one, hello world, there is no ACTION BAR on the new PROJECT